# OpenActivity and ActivityHistory SOQL restriction for standard user

Tags: apex, soql, tasks, activity, activityhistory

I am aware about other questions related to OpenActivity and ActivityHistory objects. These objects are not queryable directly so my working soql looks

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT ActivityDate, Id, LastModifiedDate FROM OpenActivities 
   ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC NULLS LAST , LastModifiedDate DESC NULLS FIRST  
   LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0)
 FROM Account WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST  LIMIT 1
```

It works pretty well for user with a system administrator profile. However the issue exists for salesforce standard users. I get this error.

```
There is an implementation restriction on OpenActivities. 
When you query this relationship, security evaluation is implemented for users 
who don't have administrator permissions, 
and you must use a specific sort order: ActivityDate ASC, LastModifiedDate DESC
```

The root of this issue is offset value in my soql. When I remove it works fine. But I need offset in my soql for lazy loading. Any thoughts about it?